# Flex: is it possible to access default `mx:Tree` icons?

Tags: apache-flex, tree, icons, flex3

I have a bit of a problem, in that I have a tree:

```
<mx:Tree iconField="@icon" />
```

That's been fine for a while, but now I want *parts* of the tree to have their default icons. Now, for reasons I haven't figured out yet, the `icon` member of the source XML is ignored for branch nodes, and the default is used But for leaf nodes, I *must* have a valid `icon` member, or I get an exception. `icon=""` doesn't work.

Taking a look under the hood, I ran:

```
trace('The default tree icon: ' + tree.itemToIcon(tree.selectedItem).toString());
```

which revealed the default to be:

> class _TreeStyle__embed_css_Assets_swf_TreeNodeIcon_770392128

which is way too magic string. No thanks. I didn't even try assign that to `icon`.

Rather than do a screen cap, Gimp edit, and then make it into a custom icon, how do I simply reference the default icon that the platform provides?

Flex 3.5 SDK here.

Comment: I'd be more tempted to use the function you use above without the toString() on some node that is known to have the default icon, then assign that to a variable that you could then set as the icon field in your XML.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship That might not be such a bad workaround. The code would look a bit ugly, but at least I wouldn't have to make a whole new icon. It might not work, though. I can see `itemToIcon()` failing unless the dummy tree I make is allowed to make it through to its "creation" phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Amy's suggestion, I tried:

```
public var m_icoDefaultLeaf:Class;
private static var m_oDummyTree:Tree;
private static var m_xmlDummy:XML;
```

...

```
m_oDummyTree = new Tree;
m_xmlDummy = <dummynode />;
m_oDummyTree.dataProvider = m_xmlDummy;
m_oDummyTree.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE,
        function (evt:FlexEvent):void {
            m_icoDefaultLeaf = m_oDummyTree.itemToIcon(m_xmlDummy);
            removeChild(m_oDummyTree);
            m_oDummyTree = null;
            m_xmlDummy = null;
        }
);
addChild(m_oDummyTree);
```

Then I just used `icon="m_icoDefaultLeaf"` in the XML for the leaves and amazingly, it worked!

Yes, it does have to be that complicated. I had to handle that event, and I had to add the tree as a child of something.

And another thing I tried, was to erase all that code and just use

```
public var m_icoDefaultLeaf:Class = null;
```

But that just made a blank icon, not a default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do over think & with that over complicate everything!
I have not worked with this a long time, but maybe this still could help you a little.From memory I had more complex once as well but have not looked at any of it quiet awhile! [One Link of many I used with Tree setup](http://www.uppercut-spottheartography.webflashartistry.com/)

```
gallery icon="iconSymbol0AG"

gallery label="    AR - ARGENTINA" src="com/assets/images/countriesFlagsRoundLarge/ar.png"

gallery label=" Mauricio Photography" src="com/assets/images/PageOne/PhotographyBlogs/BlankArtists/AR/TheMauricioBlog.swf"

file label=" Web Site" icon="iconSymbolAR" src="com/assets/images/PageOne/PhotographyBlogs/WebSites/AR/TheCollazosBlog.swf"

gallery
```

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't get this at all. I want to access the default leaf icon in an `mx:Tree` and use it for my own purposes. I don't see how your answer leads to that.